# Showing discrete variable in a single geom_sina/violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I'm trying to create a plot with `geom_sina` and `geom_violin` where all data points are plotted together (as one violin shape) and are coloured by a factor.

However, when I specify `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = "", y = mpg, fill = am))`, the plot is split according to the factor, which is what I'd like to avoid (plot 1). The closest I've come is treating the factor as a continuous variable (plot 2). But then the legend displays a "fill" bar and not the discrete factor levels I'd like.

So, if possible, I'd like the plot to stop splitting by colour when using a factor, or to overide the legend to discrete values if going with numerics.

Any help is much appreciated : )

[plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzvYy.png)
[plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbJ38.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. Using the `group` aesthetic you could overwrite the default grouping by `fill` or `color` or ...:

Note: As you want the points do be colored I switched to the `color` aesthetic.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = "", y = mpg)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_sina(aes(color = factor(am), group = 1))
```

[image]